# Parsing App.Config data to a list of objects

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, object, app-config

First off I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is, but here is my scenario, I have a large number of accounts that need to be read in a test suite. I was going to store them in xml format in the app.config file and read the accounts that way. Is this the best way to do it? Should I use JSON instead?
Anyways, I've tried to follow this method here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6730/Custom-Objects-From-the-App-Config-file
Although I use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()`; instead of `ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig()` since it is deprecated. However I had to download a custom ConfigSectionHandler which I was always getting a null pointer exception when trying to use.

The xml I am trying to parse is in the format:

```
<testConfig>
    <accounts>
        <account>
            <name>foo</name>
            <password>bar</password>
            <description/>cool account</description>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>bar</name>
            <password>foo</password>
            <description/>uncool account</description>
        </account>
    </accounts>
</testConfig>
```

It would be nice if I could parse it into a List of Account objects, I already have the Account class defined

Comment: Have you considered storing it in a separate XML file, then using LINQ to SQL to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

Use `var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);` If you'll load XML to string and put it in a XDocument. However, you can simply just use `var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLPathGoesHere");` to load xml directly.

Sample Account Object:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then use LINQ query below:

```
var accounts = (from xElem in xDoc.Descendants("account")
                select new Account()
                {
                    Name = xElem.Element("name").Value ?? string.Empty,
                    Password = xElem.Element("password").Value ?? string.Empty,
                    Description = xElem.Element("description").Value ?? string.Empty
                }).ToList();
```

Please also take a note the part of your XML,`<description/>uncool account</description>`. I guess this part should be `<description>uncool account</description>`.

**RESULT ON MY LINQ Pad Dump**

[image]